# What is the meaning and history behind the velvet signs decorating Abraham's tomb?

Tags: history, abraham

I was recently reading up on Wikipedia regarding the Tomb of the Patriarchs, and was particularly interested in this picture: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Cenotaph_of_Abraham_-_northwestern_view.JPG

I'd like to learn about the signs with Hebrew writing (on what seems to be black velvet?) *and the history behind them*. Relevant meta discussion: [Is it appropriate to ask what the signs near the tomb of Abraham have written upon them, and some of the history behind those signs?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3580/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-what-the-signs-near-the-tomb-of-abraham-have-written-up)

Comment: Those look new,never saw them there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meaning:

On our right:

A quote from Genesis 24 (1):
“And Abraham was old, advanced in days, and the L-rd had blessed Abraham with everything.  (Genesis 24)”

On our left:

A quote from the Talmud Bovo Basro 16b:
“Rabbi Shimon Ben Yochai said, 'A jewel (literally good stone) was suspended from the neck of Abraham our father so any sick person who saw it was immediately cured. 
(Bovo Basro 16b)”

Background/history on the [Talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) – please follow the link.